# In Shake, does the definition order of Rules matter?

Tags: shake-build-system

If I have a general build rule for `*.o` object files but a more specific build rule for a `foo.o` object file, does the definition order matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the documentation for [`%>`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake-0.18.3/docs/Development-Shake.html#v:-37--62-) operator:

> Patterns with no wildcards have higher priority than those with wildcards, and no file required by the system may be matched by more than one pattern at the same priority (see [`priority`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake-0.18.3/docs/Development-Shake.html#v:priority) and [`alternatives`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake-0.18.3/docs/Development-Shake.html#v:alternatives) to modify this behaviour).

So definition order doesn't matter, but files can't match multiple rules at the same priority.

Therefore, in the case of `*.o` and `foo.o`, it'll be fine.  Here's an example (using `foo.txt` and `*.txt`):

```
import Development.Shake

main = shakeArgs shakeOptions $ do
    want ["foo.txt", "bar.txt"]
    "foo.txt" %> \out -> writeFile' out "foo"
    "*.txt"   %> \out -> writeFile' out "anything"
```

vs

```
import Development.Shake

main = shakeArgs shakeOptions $ do
    want ["foo.txt", "bar.txt"]
    "*.txt"   %> \out -> writeFile' out "anything"
    "foo.txt" %> \out -> writeFile' out "foo"
```

In both cases `foo.txt` will contain "foo" and `bar.txt` will contain "anything" because the definition for "foo.txt" doesn't contain any wildcards.

---

Alternatively, if you *want* to use definition order, you can use the [`alternatives`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake-0.18.3/docs/Development-Shake.html#v:alternatives) function which uses "first-wins" matching semantics:

```
alternatives $ do
    "hello.*" %> \out -> writeFile' out "hello.*"
    "*.txt" %> \out -> writeFile' out "*.txt"
```

`hello.txt` will match the first rule, because it's defined before.

Finally, you can directly assign the priority of a rule with the [`priority`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake-0.18.3/docs/Development-Shake.html#v:priority) function:

```
priority 4 $ "hello.*" %> \out -> writeFile' out "hello.*"
priority 8 $ "*.txt" %> \out -> writeFile' out "*.txt"
```

`hello.txt` will match the second rule, because it has a higher priority.

Comment: Great answer. One thing worth noting though is that while order doesn't usually matter, there is a function to make it matter, using the `alternatives` function. It's unclear anyone ever uses it though.

Comment: Thanks, Neil.  You're right, it definitely worth mentioning `alternatives` so I've expanded the answer to include it, with an example.